# Google Apps Script - Autofill TextBox on another web page

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, autocomplete

I've to fill a texbox in an external website with a google app script based on google sheets. Is it possible?
For exemple I've to fill the textbox named "textbox1" in the website [www.website.com](http://www.website.com),

To open the website the code is :

```
function myFunction() {
  var js = "<script>window.open('www.website.com','_blank', 'width=800, height=600'); \
      google.script.host.close(); ;</script>";
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(js);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Now loading.');
}
```

normaly the code would be
`document.getElementByName("textBox1").setAttribute("value","something")` 
but it doesn't work with google app script. Can you help me to understand how it works?

More Informations :
In my situation I have to click on a button on google sheets which will open a web page (not google suite) and automatically fill out a form (of course I know the names of the fields in advance as well as the data to put). My problem is therefore to modify an HTML page via an app script.
On Excel it was possible to do this with the InternetExplorer package which includes HTMLDocument for example.

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: I don't think you can display an external website in a Sheets sidebar, let alone modify it. See [Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions). Why do you want to do this? If you explain your situation a bit more, maybe a workaround could be found.

Comment: In my situation I have to click on a button on google sheets which will open a web page (not google suite) and automatically fill out a form (of course I know the names of the fields in advance as well as the data to put). My problem is therefore to modify an HTML page via an app script.
On Excel it was possible to do this with the InternetExplorer package which includes HTMLDocument for example.

Comment: I don't think you can programmatically fill up a form from an external website via Apps Script, due to the restrictions I mentioned before. If your ultimate purpose is to submit this form, and you know the HTTP request related to the form submission, you could in theory use [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) to make this request programmatically. But that would depend on your exact form, whether it allows programmatic submission, whether you have to be logged in, etc.